# Give write-access to subfolder on samba share

Tags: server, permissions, samba, shared-folders

I have a read-only share on my samba server, is it possible for me to make subdirectories on this share and make them writable for others/specific users?

Example:

`\\server\share Only root` write access

`\\server\share\directory`    Writable for everyone/certain users

I've tried making a directory within the share with read/write access, but it is overruled by the shares read only setting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grant write permissions in Samba?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31147/how-to-grant-write-permissions-in-samba)

Answer (score 1):

navigate to the folder using terminal

$ chmod -R 755 directory

have a look on this

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

https://mdshaonimran.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/chmod-change-filefolder-permission-in-ubuntu/